# ServerSymmetricEngine fails to start

Tags: java, spring-boot, symmetricds

I have an embedded Spring boot app. When I start the server

```
    ServerSymmetricEngine serverEngine = new ServerSymmetricEngine(new File("server.properties"));
```

It always fails when the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'domainServerExporter' defined in class path resource [symmetric-jmx.xml]: Error setting property values
Invalid property 'registrationBehaviorName' of bean class [org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter]: Bean property 'registrationBehaviorName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

What could be the issue? I have an embedded Tomcat (In spring boot), why should I expose the jmx config?

Comment: Guessing there is an incompatibility between SymmetricDS and the version of Spring you are using.  What version of each are you using?

Comment: symmetric-server : 3.5.19 and Spring boot:2.1.7

Comment: Those are incompatible.  3.5 is six years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.5 of SymmetricDS depends on Spring 3.1.2, so make sure your dependencies are correct.  But, those are old versions and no longer supported.

Instead, I recommend using the latest version of SymmetricDS.  The project switched Maven repositories a while back, so maybe you're just picking up old versions from Maven central.  Here is the current Maven repository for SymmetricDS:

http://maven.jumpmind.com/repo/

Comment: WOW, I would never know that they have another repository, I thought mavencentral was the latest.

THANK YOU! now it works.